# How to check how many threads are currently running when using TBB?

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiler, tbb

I am running Intel TBB on clusters. However, I don't know how to check how many threads are active and running. Is there a way to check this?

Let's say I have 16 cores, so I would like to know if all 16 cores are now being used in my TBB code. This would make sure there is no problem with my system.

Comment: Can you clarify what you intend to do with this information. It may have a significant effect on how you get it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Let's say I have 16 cores, so I would like to know if all 16 cores are now being used in my TBB code.

Comment: So are you worried that you might create threads and for some reason they won't run?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, is that something I should not be worried about? I sort of want to be able to debug, when the code runs significantly slower than usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to know if all 16 cores are now being used in my TBB code.

It is right to assume that requesting or expecting a number of threads in TBB is not always results in this number of threads created or then working on a user code. TBB follows optional parallelism paradigm which does not guarantee specific number of threads working concurrently. Moreover, even if TBB created enough threads, it does not mean that all the threads will be able to join a given user code; `task_scheduler_init` and `task_arena` specify only the limit for number of worker threads.

You can use `task_scheduler_observer` to monitor how many worker threads are created and how many are really joined the task arena of your concern.

[This blog](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/31/applying-intel-threading-building-blocks-observers-for-thread-affinity-on-intel) provides simple code for how to count TBB worker threads which were **created**:

```
class concurrency_tracker: public tbb::task_scheduler_observer {
    tbb::atomic<int> num_threads;
public:
    concurrency_tracker() : num_threads() { observe(true); }
    /*override*/ void on_scheduler_entry( bool ) { ++num_threads; }
    /*override*/ void on_scheduler_exit( bool ) { --num_threads; }

    int get_concurrency() { return num_threads; }
};
```

But it is not much different from an external tool which can show number of live threads in a process. In order to check how many threads are **joining** your computation region (arena), we can use a preview feature `TBB_PREVIEW_LOCAL_OBSERVER`:

```
#define TBB_PREVIEW_LOCAL_OBSERVER 1
#include <tbb/task_scheduler_observer.h>
//...
class concurrency_tracker: public tbb::task_scheduler_observer {
    tbb::atomic<int> num_threads;
    tbb::atomic<int> max_threads;
public:
    concurrency_tracker()
    :   tbb::task_scheduler_observer(true)   // request implicit arena observation
    ,   num_threads(), max_thread()
    {
        observe(true);
    }

    /*override*/ void on_scheduler_entry( bool )
    {
        int current_num = ++num_threads;    // increment instant concurrency counter
        int current_max = max_threads;
        while( current_max < current_num )  // update max concurrency value
            current_max = max_threads.compare_and_swap(current_num, current_max);
    }

    /*override*/ void on_scheduler_exit( bool ) { --num_threads; }

    int get_instant_concurrency() { return num_threads; }
    int get_peak_concurrency()    { return max_threads; }
};
```

Finally, the same trick can be done directly from inside of your parallel algorithms using TLS (e.g. `tbb::enumerable_thread_specific`) as it is implemented in `src/test/harness_concurrency_tracker.h` file from the TBB unit tests sources. It can track how many of the specific task instances were **running** in parallel.