# Using TBB for an simple example

Tags: c++, tbb

I am new to `TBB` and try to do a simple exprement.

My data for functions are:

```
int n = 9000000;
int *data = new int[n];
```

I created a function, the first one without using `TBB`:

```
void _array(int* &data, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            data[i] = busyfunc(data[i])*123;
        }
}
```

`It takes 0.456635 seconds.`

And also created a to function, the first one with using `TBB`:

```
void parallel_change_array(int* &data,int list_count) {
    //Instructional example - parallel version
    parallel_for(blocked_range<int>(0, list_count),
        [=](const blocked_range<int>& r) {
        for (int i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); i++) {
            data[i] = busyfunc(data[i])*123;
        }
    });
}
```

It takes me `0.584889 seconds.`

As for busyfunc(int m):

```
int busyfunc(int m)
{
    m *= 32;
    return m;
}
```

Can you tell me, why the function without using `TBB` spends less time, than if it is with `TBB`?

I think, the problem is that the functions are simple, and it's easy to calculate without using `TBB`.

Answer (score 4):

First, the `busyfunc()` seems not so busy because 9M elements are computed in just half a second, which makes this example rather memory bound (uncached memory operations take orders of magnitude more cycles than arithmetic operations). Memory bound computations scale not as good as compute-bound, e.g. plain memory copying usually scales up to no more than, say, 4 times even running on much bigger number of cores/processors.

Also, memory bound programs are more sensitive to NUMA effects and since you allocated this array as contiguous memory using standard C++, it will be allocated by default entirely on the same memory node where the initialization occurs. This default can be altered by running with `numactl -i all --`.

And the last, but the most important thing is that TBB initializes threads lazily and pretty slowly. I guess you do not intend writing an application which exits after 0.5 seconds spent on parallel computation. Thus, a fair benchmark should take into account all the warm-up effects, which are expected in the real application. At the very least, it has to wait until all the threads are up and running before starting measurements. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24823749/2527797) suggests one way to do that.

[update] Please also refer to Alexey's answer for another possible reason lurking in compiler optimization differences.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Anton's asnwer, I recommend to check if the compiler was able to optimize the code equivalently.

For start, check performance of the TBB version executed by a single thread, without real parallelism. You can use `tbb::global_control` or `tbb::task_scheduler_init` to limit the number of threads to 1, e.g.

```
tbb::global_control ctl(tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, 1);
```

The overheads of thread creation, as well as cache locality or NUMA effects, should not play a role when all the code is executed by one thread. Therefore you should see approximately the same performance as for the no-TBB version. If you do, then you have a scalability issue, and Anton explained possible reasons.

However if you see that performance drops a lot, then it is a serial optimization issue. One of known reasons is that some compilers cannot optimize the loop over a `blocked_range` as good as they optimize the original loop; and it was also observed that storing `r.end()` into a local variable may help:

```
    int rend = r.end();
    for (int i = r.begin(); i < rend; i++) {
        data[i] = busyfunc(data[i])*123;
    }
```